# Regex match by occurrences of certain characters

Tags: regex

Assume the string contain only two characters - k and p. What regex expression will match the strings where all pairs of k occur before pairs of p?

I have the following expression so far, but it does not catch all the cases (the ones with repeated k and ends with kk):

```
^(k*|k+p{1}|k{1}p+)[kp]*(kpkk|pk|pp|kp)$
```

Example of strings:

```
k              // match
kk             // match 
kkkkpp         // match
kkppk          // match
ppppkkp        // no match
kppppppkk      // no match
kppk           // match
kpkpkpkpkp     // match
kppkpkk        // match
```

Comment: Why does `kppk` match? the pair of `k` completes after the pair of `p`.

Comment: yeah, "all pairs of k occur before pairs of p" - why the last two are matches then?

Comment: Why should the last example match? It should be a non-match as kk comes after pp

Answer (score 2):

Try this Regex:

```
^(?!.*pp.*kk)[kp]+$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j9aN78/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!.*pp.*kk)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the current match should not have any case where `kk` comes after `pp`
- `[kp]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of either `k` or `p`
- `$` - end of the string

Comment: I would put `$` at the end to make sure there are only `k` and `p` in the entire string - if it is necessary to validate that.